# Trying to concatenate columns in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to concatenate 2 columns into 1 column for my resultset.

```
var gridInfo = from leader in db.SchoolLdrAdminAccesses
               join emp in db.Employees
               on leader.ID equals emp.ID
               select new List<string> { leader.ID, string.Format("{0}{1}", emp.FirstName, emp.LastName) };
```

**I'm getting this error:**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

What am I doing incorrectly?

I have to keep this:

```
select new List<string> {...}
```

As I am then doing this and I need it in the List structure.

```
        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = gridInfo.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = gridInfo.Count(),
            aaData = gridInfo.ToArray()
        },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Why are you selecting `leader.ID` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `+` operator to concat two strings in EF:

```
select new List<string> { leader.ID, emp.FirstName + emp.LastName };
```

Unlike `string.Format`, the query provider knows how to translate the `+`operator into SQL.

And for that matter, do the same thing to concat to strings in any other C# code that you have.  Using `string.Format` to just concat two strings is needlessly complex, thus confusing readers.

Comment: How can I add a space or a comma inbetween?

Comment: @webdad3 You concatenate the first field to a string literal, and then concat that to the next.

Comment: Like this? emp.FirstName + ' ' + emp.LastName - If so that didn't work

Comment: @webdad3 That's not a string literal.  You need to use a string literal, as the error message you got will have indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation instead. Functions like String.Format cannot be processed on the server side, which is why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a LINQ to Entities query and `String.Format` is not one of the methods that it knows how to translate.  Hence you must first convert it to a set of .Net objects and then apply the `String.Format` conversion